# Mule http connector seems to "eat" variable

Tags: variables, mule, activemq-classic, mule-flow

I have a question for you as I have't been able to resolve this myself. I have been developing a mule application that activates when a message gets posted to active mq topic. When using mule locally everything works fine, even when these messages are posted to ActiveMq topic by another system. 
I uploaded my mule application to server and in the server it only works when I post messages manually.
I am forced to use mule 3.5.1 EE.

My flow simplified: variable is read from message and then that variable is used in HTTP connector which returns XML.

**Here are my logs from the server:**

Here is how it works when called by hand (and how it work in both cases when using local mule):

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 13173178 <- this is the variable
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: correct xml file
```

This is how it works with call from another system:

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 13173178 <- this is the variable that gets lost
org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.1289595614'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.1289595614'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: empty xml file <- empty XML is returned when http gets called without flow variable
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Snippet from my code

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="myQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>

    <set-variable variableName="myvariable" value="#[xpath('string(//myvariableId)')]" doc:name="Set myvariable"/>
    <logger message="#[flowVars.myvariable]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="20007" path="mypath.OrderNumber='AD-#[flowVars.myvariable]'" method="GET" doc:name="Get XML" disableTransportTransformer="true"/>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: Please add an extract of your flow, without that we cannot help you much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in mules HTTP connector, but in the another system. The another system was too slow to process its data and my mule app running in the server was too fast. It only seemed that it was losing the variable but the reason for the false response was that it didn't have the correct response ready. Corrected the problem with a timer.

Comment: What did you do to correct? On the other system side?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do in the HTTP connector with path??

path="mypath.OrderNumber='AD-#[flowVars.myvariable]'"

your path should be a valid path something like "/mypath/test"
i don't get the point of the variable being eaten?!
you need to drop some more info to help you out.

Comment: My bad the path is actually in correct form ie. path="mypath/OrderNumber='AD-#[flowVars.myvariable]'" and what happens is that when running this in server environment with request coming straight from another system it seems to "eat" variable and the http request it sends is: path="mypath/OrderNumber='AD-'" so the variable disappears somewhere. I modified my code to such that there is a choice before the http request that checks if the variable is there, and if not http connector is not even called. However the variable is there and it goes to the http connector which loses it somehow.

Comment: So you create that variable and excpect it to persist when sending it over http? That won't work, nor flowVariables nor sessionVariables will persist over http. You should set an outbound property and pick that up as an inbound property on the other side.

Comment: Thats not it. Path in http:outbound-endpoint defines where the connector sends its message. If I would set host to "google.com" and path to "myquery/#[flowVars.myvar]" it would be equal to curling google.com/myquery/myvariable. I am not trying to send variable anywhere I am using it to set path. In my server environment the current situation would be equal to curling google.com/myquery/ because the variable gets lost somehow. Server on the other side knows what to reply based on url request.

Comment: Ah ok now i understand sorry about that, your MEL expression is encapsulated between single quotes, I think that's an issue. 'AD-#[flowVars.myvariable]'

Comment: Single quotes need to be there in order for the URL to be correct. And it works correctly 75% of the cases: when running mule locally with manual activemq posting / other service which I have no control doing the posting and when I am manually doing the posting while this runs on a server. It does not work when the other system does the posting while the application is running on a server. So can you think of any ways why server mule and local mule would behave differently? Both are running same 3.5.1 EE. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: You can see my debug prints in my first post. Problem is illustrated in first two debug prints. org.mule.transport.service seems to do something it does not do with manual activemq post.

Comment: Start by adding a logger before the request with the complete value you are posting as the path: mypath.OrderNumber='AD-#[flowVars.myvariable]' and run in on your server and check the logfile, or you already did?

Comment: Yep, the path is right until the http connector in which it seems to disappear

Comment: Try creating a temporary variable with the same value of path. mypath.OrderNumber='AD-#[flowVars.myvariable]' then log that variable before the http connector